# Change/Add to the list of names for crewmembers in FTL?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've been playing FTL for a while now, and I am seeing the same names crop up again and again in my crew members. Whilst I realise they are used for recording stats, I don't really care about them, and really just want a bit more variety in the names presented to me.

Is there a way to access the list of names used by FTL and either add to it, or at the very least change them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the list of names. Do note that names in the game were a [$100+ backer reward](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/64409699/ftl-faster-than-light) on the initial Kickstarter.

At any rate, you will need to unpack `{FTL root}/resources/data.dat` with a tool such as [ftldat](https://github.com/bwesterb/ftldat) (`ftldat unpack path/to/data.dat`).
Once unpacked, you will find a file called `{data.dat unpacked}/data/names.xml`.

You can edit this with any text editor (it does use Unix linebreaks, though, so you might want to refrain from using `notepad.exe`) to change the list. You will have to follow the same conventions the game uses, but other than that, anything is possible.

Once you're done, back up your original data.dat, repack it with ftldat (`ftldat pack path/to/data.dat`) and you're good to go.

---

As for the conventions in the `names.xml` file.

A list is wrapped in a set of `<nameList race="{race}" sex="{sex}"></nameList>` tags, where `{race}` currently seems to have no effect (or at least "human" is given to all races, no matter what. Entering another race, such as "engi" might restrict it to that given race.) and `{sex}` can be either `male` or `female`.

Inside the `nameList` tags, each name is to be added as a `<name short="{short}">{name}</name>` tag. Here, `short` is an optional attribute, but it is used to shorten names that are too long for the UI. When `{name}` includes spaces, only the last section is used ("Sir Jonathan Kirby" results in "Kirby"), unless a `short` attribute is specified.

Comment: and if you don't want to have to come up with the names manually there is an FTL mod that adds lots of names for you. http://www.ftlgame.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3293

Comment: funny that you mention the kickstarter, I just [suggested](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122860/change-add-to-the-list-of-names-for-crewmembers-in-ftl#comment165948_122860) using FTL time travel to back them ;-)

Comment: @Zommuter I saw the comment in the names.xml file while trying this stuff out and since I, personally, don't like actively undermining the Kickstarter I mentioned it. :P

Comment: Well, +1 for that. It was intended as a special reward after all. But unless a way to change the probabilities is introduced to favour backer names while still allowing other names, there's no other way to achieve more diversity (not that it annoyed me)

Comment: @Zommuter I agree, which is why I just mentioned it, rather than outright refusing to answer. ;)