# When you rename your starting characters in FTL, are those names added to the default list for later games?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I manually renamed one of my starting characters Ashley, which is a common name, but in a later game one of the crew members I got was named Ashley. I was just curious if the game adds names you manually enter to the list it pulls random names from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it doesn't.

Ashley is already in the default name list from the start.

If you do want to add names to the list, see [this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122860/). You can also use the information there to open the `names.xml` file and see the default list yourself.